# How to match card placement as in 3D render?

Tags: python, 3d, nuke

Is it possible to 3d place a card to match a 3D render?
I've exported 3d camera from my application and rendered an image.
How would you place that image in Nuke, so that in 2D view it matches exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Edit : So it sounds like the question you're asking is...

"How can I place a card in a 3d scene, with a rendered still frame on it, that perfectly fills the camera's fustrum when viewed through the exported camera that image was rendered through?"

Depending on what you've rendered, there may be issues of depth or parallax - because you're not bringing over depth information for that image plane.For example: Should it be a very small card that is close to camera, or a very large card that is far away? These will impact how that image moves as the camera animates.

Ignoring those potential problems, you can create a card that fills a camera's fustrum by making use of the parameters 'lens_in_focal' and 'lens_in_haperture'. What you need to do is link the Camera's focal distance and horizontal aperture to those parameters in the card:

lens_in_focal: Camera1.focal

lens_in_haperture : Camera1.haperture

With those set, you can change the 'z' parameter on the card to move the card further away and it will scale appropriately. If the camera is moving and you need it to stick to the camera, add a TransformGeo node beneath the card with the Camera plugged into the Axis. If you want the card to match perfectly on a specific frame, put a frameHold after the Camera before it plugs into the TransformGeo.

An alternative and perhaps easier method is to create a sphere with the camera position linked to it's pivot, and then project the image from the camera into the Sphere, then scale up the sphere as much as you need. This is sometimes handy for distant background projections.

edit : Found a nukepedia post with images that might help : http://www.nukepedia.com/written-tutorials/creating-a-3d-image-plane

Comment: I think you misunderstood a question. I've exported 3d camera from 3d application. I also rendered out the animation. The question is. How do you place a 3d card with a shader of rendered image, so that when viewed through a scanline renderer in Nuke, the images match.

Comment: Right now, I just manually try to position the card. I turn on to render it's wireframe and using transforms trying to match its position so the lines are straight when viewed through scanline renderer.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, I think you're trying to create an image plane to fill the camera's fustrum - is that right?

Comment: I guess you're right... I have seen this technique but haven't tried it yet, I will see if I have time to test it out, but basically I just want to match 3d card xyz rotation to the first frame of the camera. So that my 3d card is not distorted but facing the camera completely flat at first frame.